# C++: Hiding members in subclasses. Does it make sense?

Tags: c++, oop

I've just came across using-directive in a context, which is new for me - e.g "moving" a member of parent class from public to private. I've tested the example below and two question arose:

1. Is the code at (1) portable? According to standard it should be deprecated.
2. Does it make sense at all to hide public members in subclasses? 
   (I think in Java the access could be made only less strict in subclasses.)

Code format bug

```
class A{
public:
  A():_i(1975){}
  int _i;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  B():_i(333){}
  int i()const{ return _i;}
private:
  int _i; // (1)depricated? no warning in VS2008?
};

class C : public A
{
public:
  C(){} //_i initialized by A
  int i()const{ return _i+1;}
private:
  using A::_i; //(2) should be the right way
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  int i= b.i(); //value of B::_i (333)
  int a_i = static_cast<A*>(&b)->_i; //value of A::_i (1975)

  C c;
  int ca_i = c.i(); //value of A::_i via getter (1975+1)
  //however, A::_i is still accessible  
  a_i = static_cast<A*>(&c)->_i; //value of A::_i (1975)

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code shows two different things: The B class has two independent members named `_i` while the C class has only one member `_i` (from its base class)

Comment: @Martin, Yes, that's what I've intended. The variant with C is "how it should be". Trying to hide _i in B hides the name "_i" but A::_i is still there. This was not obvious for me till I came across using-derective in this context. I'm jus curious, why VS2008 doesn't warn me. :-(

Comment: You are not *trying to* hide `_i` in B! The (implied) intention of the B code is simply to have a member of name `_i`. That this new `_i` happens to have the same name as the member in the base class is just (implied) coincidence and name hiding could be considered as an unfortunate side effect. Warnings are purely optional from the std POV and MS just decided that a warning is not neccessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

ad (1): I don't see any reason why this should be deprecated.  I think it's perfectly legal C++. (The class `B` adds a second copy of `_i` which shadows the `_i` in `A`, but you can still access the latter by `b.A::_i`.)

ad (2): That does not seem useful at all to me, since you can still access `_i` in `c` by using `c.A::_i`, so it isn't hidden at all.

Comment: (1) According to "ANSI/ISO C++ Professional Programmer's Handbook" Chapter2 it was deprecated. (2) To me too. I'm trying to find out if there is a use-case for it :-)

Answer (score 1):

However ugly this code is for me... ( just aesthetic personnal feeling ok).

It is **not a hidden member**. It is an **added member**.
There is two `i` in this code. `A::_i` and `B::_i`.

After that one can play. But I really dislike when code is misleading in such a way.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've forgotten to mention that this is an example code (-: Sorry for short names and missing Doxygen comments :-) Yes indeed, class B is misleading. It was my intention to show that it is. It was not obvious for me that the member is added. I've expected the compiler to give me a warning :-(

Comment: @Valentin, don't worry man, I'm just reacting. And don't worry for comments, I am used to (most would say it's a bad habit) of putting the less comments possible, I try to have talkative function name and variables that say what they do, and do what they say. The compiler won't give warning because it is a C++ feature, you can always create a variable that has the same name of another that has a greater scope of life, not only for class members, but also in plain functions.

Answer (score 1):

For your amusement, the [GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm) discussion on C++ hiding features :-)

Comment: :-) Yes I new this article. However, none of those techniques are applied in my example. I was neither a liar, thief nor lawer :-)